# Using Angular 2's TestComponentBuilder confuses me

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I'm working on an Angular 2-rc3 application and I have some unittests set up and they're working, yay! I just don't understand why they have to be written the way they do. And even more amazing, [all](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/testing-angular-2-components-unit-tests-testcomponentbuilder/) [the](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-unit-testing-with-jasmine-defe20421584#.xwz347m87) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046599/can-testcomponentbuilder-test-an-angular-component-within-a-component) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863501/angular-2-testcomponentbuilder-error-typeerror-attempted-to-assign-to-readon) [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486476/angular2-and-karma-issue) have the same approach. Specifically, these questions are on the top of my list:

1. Why is the `TestComponentBuilder` configured in every unittest?

   ```
   it('shows list of blog items by default', inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
       return tcb
       .overrideProviders(BlogRoll, [provide(BlogService, {
               useValue: mockBlogService
           })])
           .createAsync(BlogRoll)
           .then((fixture) => {
           // actual test code
       });
   });
   ```

   That's already seven lines of code extra per unittest and the readability of my code suffers a lot from this. I've tried placing this in a `beforeEach()`:

   ```
   beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
       console.log('beforeEach');
       return tcb.overrideProviders(BlogRoll, [provide(BlogService, {
               useValue: mockBlogService
           })])
           .createAsync(BlogRoll)
           .then(fixture => {
               // this never gets printed
               console.log('in then:', fixture.componentInstance);
           });
   }));
   ```

   but Karma doesn't seem to be able to handle the asyncness, everything in the `then` just doesn't get executed. Is this a bug or is this intended, are we not supposed to do it like this?
2. Why does the creation of this component need to happen asynchronous? There's a `createSync()` on the [TestComponentBuilder class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/compiler/testing/TestComponentBuilder-class.html), can't we use that? Of course I tried it and found out that the function signatures differ: `createAsync(rootComponentType: Type) : Promise<ComponentFixture<any>>` and `createSync(componentFactory: ComponentFactory<C>) : ComponentFixture<C>`. Why do we need a component factory here, why don't we need it when creating the component async? **// Update**: RC4 is out and `createSync()` now accepts a Type. Great.

My sanity thanks you already!

Comment: Update: The changelog for RC4 contains this breaking change: `compiler: TestComponentBuilder.createSync now takes a component type and throws if not all templates are either inlined are compiled before via createAsync.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2 final has shipped and the `TestComponentBuilder` class has been replaced by the [TestBed](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html), which confuses me a whole lot less.

Comment: here are the [docs](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/components/overriding.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. The [angular2-material](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/components/button/button.spec.ts) tests are nicely organised, and setup `TestComponentBuilder` in the beforEach, although they do still call `createAsync` for each test. You can then nest the `createAsync` call like this:

   ```
   describe('Example', () => {
           let fixture;
           let builder: TestComponentBuilder;

           beforeEach(injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
                   builder = tcb;

                   builder.createAsync(ExampleComponent).then(        
                        fixture = f;
                   });
           });


           it('Test 1', () => {
                        expect(fixture.componentInstance).not.toEqual(null);
           });
   });
   ```

Comment: Did you test this code? Your `then` contains a syntax error (`f => {` is missing). One major difference with my code is that you're using `injectAsync()` which I hadn't tried yet, but unfortunateliy, on my machine the results are the same and the `then` does not get executed whatsoever. Does it get executed with you?

Comment: Hold the phone! I get an actual error: `No Directive annotation found on MyPipe`. No idea why though. My application is working, but my test can't find my pipe? The test is in the same directory as my pipe, `import { MyPipe } from './my.pipe';` is correct... Weird.